# CMAKE: File is not recognized ( Cross Compiling ). From Linux to Windows (32 bit)

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking

System: Debian 11

Project Tree

```
C_UPDATER/
   Main/
     ...(.cpp files)
   App/
     ...(.cpp files)
   Loader.cpp
```

In .cpp file i am using **"#include <curl/curl.h>"**

I am using global include and lib folders.

```
➜  ~ sudo find / -name libcurl.a
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libcurl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
```

```
➜  ~ sudo find / -name curl.h
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/curl/curl.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h
```

I have following CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(updater)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32" CACHE PATH "Cmake install prefix")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /)
# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE NEVER)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
# Include libcurl header files
include_directories(/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include)

add_library(AppModules Main/Main.cpp)

# Link against libcurl library
target_link_libraries(AppModules CURL::libcurl)

# Set compiler options
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -static -static-libstdc++ -lpthread -lstdc++ -lcurl")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-DCURL_STATICLIB -static -static-libstdc++ -lpthread -lcurl")

# Add executable target
add_executable(updater Loader.cpp)

# Link against AppModules library
target_link_libraries(updater AppModules)
```

And i get following Error.

```
➜  C_Updater make
[ 50%] Built target AppModules
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable updater
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/updater.dir/build.make:105: updater] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:97: CMakeFiles/updater.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

As i understand the problem is that **find_package** function is searching for **libcurl.so** instead of **libcurl.a**.

I tried to add following lines to tell him there to search.
But this error still persist.

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32" CACHE PATH "Cmake install prefix")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /)
# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE NEVER)
```

Also i tried to do like this. But it seems not right.

```
target_link_libraries(AppModules /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libcurl.a)
```

Comment: Setting variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` in the `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong. The same is about `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`/`CMAKE_C_COMPILER`. For cross-compile, these variables should be set in a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling).